# What does 为 mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 17日，国家统计局发布上半年中国经济数据，GDP增速为6.9%，延续了稳中有进、稳中向好的发展态势。

What does the 为 mean? How does it function in the sentence grammatically?

Comment: ＂汉语水平考试词典＂：为 wéi［义４］是＜书＞（be;mean (written)):言～心声｜本科学习期限～四年｜北京被定～中国的首都｜印刷术、火药、指南针、纸统称～四大发明｜＜红楼梦＞的作者～曹雪芹。

Comment: @user6065 I thought 增速 is a verb, not a noun. But then is there any difference from 是? Maybe I shall file a new question...

Comment: here "growth rate", cf.bkrs: 增速 to speed up
to accelerate
growth rate (economics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*为* means *is*, we can also say *GDP增速是6.9%*. In a formal academic essay(e.g. mathematics, science), people usually choose *为*, which is more serious and rigorous. This sentence is from a report of government, so it should be **serious**.

Answer (score 1):

Means 是

e.g.

他的身高**为**8尺.

他的身高**是**8尺.